# Retrieving list of objects with data plus count of rows in join

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF query in an ASP.NET MVC project, EF 6. To form my data I have 2 joins, I then have to iterate through them to resolve some other properties, notably the number of records from another table.

What I am trying to do is refactor the code to get the count during the query.

Here is my attempt, the join on the leads table is what I am working through.

```
var orderItems = dataContext.ES_OrderDetail
                .Join(dataContext.ES_Products, od => od.ProductID, p => p.ProductID, (od, p) => new { od, p })
                .Join(dataContext.ES_Orders, od => od.od.OrdID, o => o.OrdID, (od, o) => new { od, o })
                .Join(dataContext.leads, od => new { DID = od.od.od.DeviceID,  CID = od.o.CompanyID.Value, EID = od.o.EventId.Value }, 
                    l => new { DID = l.unitID, CID = l.companyID, EID = l.eventID }, (od,l) => new { order = od.o, odetail = od.od, lead = l })
```

With this query I Select() from it into an object to get the various data I need, for example:

```
.Select(s => new OutputClass
{
    OrderId = s.order.OrdId,
    ItemId = s.odetail.od.ItemId,
    //etc
}.ToList();
```

What I would like to do is, within the Select(), have something like

```
LeadCount = s.leads.Count()
```

but leads is a reference to the entity, in short I am unsure how I can join an entity but perform an aggregate on it, rather than access the data. As it stands after I call Select() I then loop over each and perform another query to get the count.

Comment: You need to use `GroupJoin` which may or may not translate to SQL, depending. You could also do a `Join` followed by `GroupBy`...

Answer (score 0):

NetMage is right about group join. Group join will give you what you need (`leads.Count()`). I did change the method syntax to query syntax. Query syntax is more readable for me in this case (you can read more about the two syntax here: https://michaelscodingspot.com/when-to-use-c-linq-with-query-syntax-over-method-syntax/).

The query below is using `LeadId` primary key column but this might change in your code. I didn't know what is the primary key for `Lead` table.

```
var orderItemsNew = (from orderDetail in dataContext.ES_OrderDetail
                 join product in dataContext.ES_Products on orderDetail.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                 join order in dataContext.ES_Orders on orderDetail.OrdID equals order.OrdID
                 join lead in dataContext.leads on new { DID = orderDetail.DeviceID, CID = order.CompanyID.Value, EID = order.EventId.Value } equals
                                                   new { DID = lead.unitID, CID = lead.companyID, EID = lead.eventID}
                 group lead.LeadId by new {
                        OrderId = order.OrdId,
                        ItemId = orderDetail.ItemId
                        // etc
                    }
                 into leadCountJoin 
                 select new OutputClass 
                 {
                    LeadCount = leadCountJoin.Count()
                    OrderId = leadCountJoin.Key.OrderId,
                    ItemId = leadCountJoin.Key.ItemId,
                    // etc
                 });
```

You can also list the necessary keys to group lead records. For now only the `OrderId` and the `ItemId` is part of the query but ptobably you will need to list more keys than two.

P.S.: If you stuck using the group by statement please provide the whole query with all `OutputClass` properties.